# Inline SVG in HTML, with Firefox 3.5

Tags: firefox, svg, inline

I'm trying to create some mixed HTML/SVG content and having some trouble. The HTML content shows up as expected, but the inline SVG does not. So, I do some experiments.

I find sites which have examples of inline SVG, and they render correctly on my system. So, I "view page source" and copy/paste the HTML/SVG into another local file, and open this file in Firefox. No inline SVG is visible.

I also tried the same experiment with Chrome, same results.

What might I be missing?

**Update**
Slight change in identity on my part: k montgomery -> kmontgom on use of OpenID.

Anyway thanks to all those who answered. The best solution was in setting the Response.ContentType; this lets me continue on with the WebForms approach for now.

I had contemplated making pure XHTML content in .xml files and using ASP.NET MVC to serve up that content. I may end up doing that in the future.

Now, onward with jQuery, SVG, and making the thing do something.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 13):

An alternative if you don't want to do XHTML is to base64 encode the SVG data.

e.g.

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" 
        data="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PCFET0NUWVBFI...etc..."></object>
```

I think this is probably not what you want specifically for your situation, but anyway, may be useful for others.

Comment: This is an interesting mechanism, but limited (especially due to inconsistent browser support).  Some additional information here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Answer (score 11):

In order for inline SVG to be shown in browsers, the page must be XHTML valid and must be served with **application/xhtml+xml** mime-type server response header.

It is also possible to pull inline SVG content from HTML page as well, see an example of an [SVG Tiger](http://www.amplesdk.com/examples/markup/svg/tiger/) image that can also be viewed in Internet Explorer (5.5+)

Comment: ASP.NET example: `Response.ContentType = "application/xhtml+xml"`

Comment: Note that this shouldn't be an issue in future versions of Firefox.  See http://hsivonen.iki.fi/test-html5-parsing/

Comment: For reference, here's a simple page showing XHTML+multiple SVG+JS: http://phrogz.net/SVG/convert_path_to_polygon.xhtml

Answer (score 5):

Make sure to name the file ".xml" not ".html"

Comment: Thanks! That works. Now the next question is how to make ASP.NET generate a .XML file instead of .HTM or .HTML

Comment: 'fraid I don't know the answer to that one

Comment: k montgomery, I guess you can set a mime-type header, see my reply for details.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I spent an entire day trying to make this work. Even setting a meta content=application/xhtml+xml didn't work.

Comment: Here is some more info on that. There's a differnet if the file is opened locally or if it is served.
http://wiki.svg.org/Inline_SVG#Choosing_a_Filename_Extension

Answer (score 3):

As Greg said, it needs to be a file that Firefox recognises as an XHTML file, not just regular HTML, which is what that renaming accomplished.  In order to get that from a server-side app, you need to set the response's `Content-type` header to `application/xhtml+xml`.

Answer (score 2):

If you dynamically generate the SVG using javascript it works inline.  Instead of:

```
    <svg id="mysvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="1000" width="1000">
        <rect id="myrect" x="0" y="0" rx="0" ry="0" width="200" height="300" fill="yellow" stroke="purple" stroke-width="5" />
   </svg>
```

You write:

```
    <script>
        var svg = document.createElementNS( "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg" );
        svg.setAttribute( "xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg/" );
        svg.setAttribute( "xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" );
        svg.setAttribute( "height", "1000" );
        svg.setAttribute( "width", "1000" );
        document.body.appendChild( svg ); 
        var rect = document.createElementNS( "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect" );
        rect.setAttribute( "id", "myrect" );
        rect.setAttribute( "x", "0" );
        rect.setAttribute( "y", "0" );
        rect.setAttribute( "rx", "0" );
        rect.setAttribute( "ry", "0" );
        rect.setAttribute( "width", "200" );
        rect.setAttribute( "height", "300" );
        rect.setAttribute( "fill", "yellow" );
        rect.setAttribute( "stroke", "purple" );
        rect.setAttribute( "stroke-width", "5" );
        svg.appendChild( rect );
    </script>
```

It's not ideal but it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

For people having this problem with ASP.NET, change the doctype to HTML5 and content-type to application/xhtml+xml, I tried it on IE9, FF 3.6 and Chrome 13:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
.....
etc
```

And in code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.Response.ContentType = "application/xhtml+xml";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others note, as long as you're using XHTML and your namespaces are correct, you're good to go - you can just use the <svg> tag right there in the HTML.

I found in testing that it only worked really well in Firefox 4 and recent Chrome builds, but YMMV. For stuff on an intranet where you know everyone is using a decent browser this is fine.

I've done some [experimentation in generating inline SVG using JavaScript](http://defi.ant.ly/2011/06/inline-svg-experiment/). Feel free to check that out, you might find the code useful.

Comment: Thanks Luís, that's fixed now.