# Embedding SVG in HTML without a link

Tags: html, svg, embedded-resource

Ok, so I know how to place a static SVG into html:

```
<object data="your.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
   <img src="yourfallback.jpg" />
</object>
```

But, how do I place the actual SVG document (eliminating the link to save an http request):

```
<object data='<path d="m315.9,581.1c.....1,22.8z" fill="#fff" stroke="#4ea3ff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="36"></path>' type="image/svg+xml">
  <img src="yourfallback.jpg" />
</object>
```

I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a data URI of the svg if you want to keep using the object tag, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3365176/109374) for the details.

Comment: Thanks, I will use the dataURI

Answer (score 0):

Just paste in the svg. But you'll need to start it with an `<svg>` tag though, you can't just use a raw `<path>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg height="190">
  <polygon points="100,10 40,180 190,60 10,60 160,180"
  style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;">
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But, that's less supported than SVG as an object [link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg) vs [link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-html5).  Also, with the <object> tag, I get a PNG fallback for free, right?

Comment: You think that users of Opera mini will form a large part of the viewers of your site?

Comment: Older versions of Safari and iOS too...together its enough to prefer the dataURI